# How to match multiple strings using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, palindrome

I have a bunch of strings to match for Bonfire: Palindrome in FreeCodeCamp
The strings are:

- eye
- racecar
- not a palindrome
- A man, a plan, a canal. Panama
- nope
- almostomla
- My age is 0, 0 si ega ym.
- 1 eye for of 1 eye.
- 0_0 (: /-\ :) 0-0

My Code:

```
function palindrome(str) {


  var newstr = str.replace(/[^\w_-]/g,"").toLowerCase();
  var num = newstr.length;
  for(var i=0;i<=Math.floor(num/2);i++)  
    {
      if(newstr[i]!==newstr[num-i])
        {

          return newstr;

       }
    }

  return true;
}
```

What could be wrong in the if statement? the return of the string is alright.. Just can't wrap my head around these Regular expressions?

My current regular expression:

```
var newstr = str.replace(/[^\w_-]/g,"").toLowerCase();
```

matches almost all the strings but the last one. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: underscore is included in `\w`, you don't need to list that separately in the regexp.

Comment: You're accessing outside the string. When `i` is zero, you compare it with `newstr[num]`, but the highest index is `newstr[num-1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while the answers were useful, they did not provide a correct regular expression. Shoot out to @Barmar for pointing at the right direction. This is my regular expression.

```
var newstr = str.replace(/[\W_]/g,'').toLowerCase();
```

The full code for Palindrome in FCC:

```
function palindrome(str) {


  var newstr = str.replace(/[\W_]/g,'').toLowerCase();
  var num = newstr.length;
  for(var i=0;i<=Math.floor(num/2);i++)  
    {
      if(newstr[i]!==newstr[num-1-i])
        {

          return false;

       }
    }

  return true;
}



palindrome("0_0 (: /-\ :) 0-0");
```

Answer (score 1):

The last one is not a palindrome; you have 0_0 at the beginning, 0-0 at the end, and do not erase those characters.

As a pedantic note, this is not, strictly speaking, a regular language.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes in an array or string run from `0` to `length-1`. But when you access the elements at the end of the string, you're going from `num`, not `num-1`. You need to subtract an additional `1` when you subtract from the end. So it should be:

```
if (newstr[i] != newstr[num-i-1]) {
    return newstr;
}
```